# How to understand independent events' set structure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

$\Omega_1=\{A,B,C\}
\\
\sigma(\Omega_1)=\{\varnothing,\{A\},\{B\},\{C\},\{A,B\},\{A,C\},\{B,C\},\{A,B,C\}\}
\\
\mathsf P_1(\{A\})=1/3,\mathsf P_1(\{B\})=1/2,\mathsf P_1(\{C\})=1/6
\\
\Omega_2=\{D,E\}
\\
\sigma(\Omega_2)=\{\varnothing,\{D\},\{E\},\{D,E\}\}
\\
\mathsf P_2(\{D\})=1/3,\mathsf P_2(\{E\})=2/3
\\
\Omega=\{(A,D),(A,E),(B,D),(B,E),(C,D),(C,E)\}
\\
\sigma(\Omega)=\{\varnothing,\{(A,D)\},\{(A,E)\},\{(B,D)\},\{(B,E)\},\{(C,D)\},\{(C,E)\},\{(A,D),(A,E)\},\{(A,D),(B,D)\},......,\{(A,D),(A,E),(B,D),(B,E),(C,D),(C,E)\}\}
$

If $A,D$ are independent, $\mathsf P(\{A\} \cap \{D\})=\mathsf P(\{(A,D)\})=\mathsf P_1(\{A\})\cdot\mathsf P_2(\{D\})$

Is it correct to say $\{A\} \cap \{D\}$ so that $A, D$ are independent events?
But isn't $\{A\} \cap \{D\}=\varnothing$? Are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: You haven't given any probabilities in your problem, so we can't determine whether A and D are independent or not. (Note that mutually exclusive events usually are NOT independent; the exception is if A or D is the empty set.)

Comment: I'm just wandering why P({A} intersect {D})<>0

Comment: You have to give me the probabilities $P$ in your problem, in order for me to determine that. I don't know what A and D represent.

Comment: How does that look like?

Comment: Isn't {A} intersect {D} empty set?

Comment: You still haven't given enough of the problem to determine the answer. Now, I need to know $P(A)$.

Comment: Okay. Now what is $P(A\cap D)$? Nevermind that; you're using $\{A\}$ and $\{D\}$. Now I can answer.

Comment: $\{A\}$ is an element of the sigma algebra of $\Omega_1$, $\{D\}$ is an element of the sigma algebra of $\Omega_2$, and $\mathsf P$ is a measure on the sigma algebra of $\Omega$. As such $\mathsf P(\{A\}\cap\{D\})$ doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following are given: $P(\{A\})=\frac{1}{3}$, $P(\{D\})=\frac13$, and $P(\{A\}\cap \{D\}) = P(\emptyset)=0$ (assuming that $A\not=D$). Since 
$$P(\{A\})\cdot P(\{D\}) = \frac{1}{9}\not=0 =  P(\{A\} \cap \{D\}),$$ the events $\{A\}$ and $\{D\}$ are *not* independent.

They *are* mutually exclusive, because $\{A\}\cap \{D\}=\emptyset$.

(Note that if $A=D$, then $P(\{A\}\cap \{D\}) = P(\{A\})=\frac{1}{3}$, which *still* isn't $\frac19$, so they wouldn't be independent here, either.)

Comment: But intuitively the result of event A has no effect on event D. So the definition are just vague in reality in this case?

Answer (score 0):

$\{A\}$ is an element of the sigma algebra of $\Omega_1$, $\{D\}$ is an element of the sigma algebra of $\Omega_2$, and $\mathsf P$ is a measure on the sigma algebra of $\Omega$.   As such $\mathsf P(\{A\}\cap\{D\})$ doesn't really make much sense.

What you want is: $\mathsf P(\{A\}{\times}\{D\})$.

---

Okay, you have three probability spaces:

- $\langle \Omega_1, \sigma(\Omega_1), \mathsf P_1\rangle$

  - Where $\sigma(\Omega_1)=\mathcal P(\Omega_1), \mathsf P_1 : \sigma(\Omega_1) \to [0;1]$
- $\langle\Omega_2, \sigma(\Omega_2), \mathsf P_2\rangle$

  - Where $\sigma(\Omega_2)=\mathcal P(\Omega_2), , \mathsf P_2 : \sigma(\Omega_2) \to [0;1]$
- $\langle \Omega, \sigma(\Omega), \mathsf P\rangle$

  - Where $\Omega = \Omega_1\times\Omega_2, \sigma(\Omega) = \mathcal P(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2), \mathsf P : \sigma(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2) \to [0;1]$

    - Further, $P_1,P_2$ are marginals. $\mathsf P_1(X) = \mathsf P(X\times\{D, E\}) \\ \mathsf P_2(Y) = \mathsf P(\{A, B, C\}\times Y)$

---

That is, $\Omega$ is the cross product of $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$.   As such, $\{A\}\not\in\sigma(\Omega)$.   However, $\{A\}{\times}\Omega_2$ is.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P_1(\{A\}) & = \mathsf P(\{A\}{\times}\Omega_2) \\ &= \mathsf P(\{(A,D), (A,E)\})\end{align}$$

What you are calling $\{A\}\cap\{D\}$ should be $(\{A\}{\times}\Omega_2)\cap (\Omega_1{\times}\{D\})$.

$$\mathsf P((\{A\}{\times}\Omega_2)\cap(\Omega_1{\times}\{D\})) = \mathsf P(\{(A, D)\})$$

At this point we *can't* simply assert that: $\mathsf P(\{(A, D)\})=\mathsf P_1(\{A\})\cdot\mathsf P_2(\{D\})$.   It *could* be so, but it *may* not be so.   However, *if* the event of $A$ happening in $\langle\Omega_1,\sigma(\Omega_1), \mathsf P_1\rangle$ is independent of the event of $D$ happening in $\langle\Omega_2,\sigma(\Omega_2), \mathsf P_2\rangle$, *then* it is the case.